# how to run pm2 with "npm run start"

Tags: pm2, npm-run

So i have an app that was built for me and I need to keep it running. but the app was built with the instructions of running it with

```
npm run start
```

I am trying to figure our how to do this using either the ecosystem.config.js or command line arguments.

I tryed

```
pm2 start npm --name "myApp" -- run "start-test"
```

But the pm2 log shows an exit code of 1.

So what is the propepr way to accomplish this?

Comment: Have u configured your package.json properly

Comment: run `pm2 logs`, then fix the error